# Amalgamating a second texmf-local tree with my current texlive installation

Tags: texlive, mac, ubuntu, texmf-local

I have a tarball of a texmf-local folder from a friend's ubuntu installation, that I'd like to amalgamate with my own texlive installation (presumably to texmf-local too). I imagine I can amalgamate the tree structure, but please what further commands are needed to refresh the config files, font-name files ... etc on my OS Texlive v.1.49 (and Catalina) installation? How can I best go about this?